# GUI hard-freezes on Ubuntu MATE 16.04

Tags: 16.04, xorg, mate, ubuntu-mate

Everything worked flawlessly until after an update. Now, when booting in graphical mode I get a black screen with an immovable mouse cursor in the middle. No response, Caps Lock doesn't affect LEDs, no Ctr-Alt-anything.

If I change to text mode, I don't get all virtual text terminals, only one, and it doesn't get focus by default. I can go to it with Alt-F1 and am able to log in. If i run `startx` it draws the top and down MATE panels and then freezes again in the same way. Only a power button poweroff gets me out.

I'm using an old, unupdateable installation of LMDE on dual boot to use the machine that contains the broken Ubuntu system. From it, `lspci` gets me this:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation H61 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 4 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 2 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 05)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8152 v2.0 Fast Ethernet (rev c1)
```

Comment: Can it be moved there?

Comment: Wait a sec. This question IS about Ubuntu. I'm only using LMDE as a backup, in order to be able to get the lspci listing!